# Embedding QuickChart.io image in HTML from Django app

Tags: html, django

I'm very new to HTML and web development so forgive me is this is an easy fix. QuickChart.io provides an image after calling the API. I've created a Django application that creates a custom URL to call QuickChart in my view file but struggling to have it appear when loading the page.

My HTML is the following:

```
{% block content %}
    <img src=quickchart_url>
    <p>{{ quickchart_url }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

My view is the following:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from quickchart import QuickChart

def about(request):
    return render(request, 'stormglass_web_client/about.html', {'quickchart_url': qc_url})

qc = QuickChart()
qc.width = 500
qc.height = 300
qc.device_pixel_ratio = 2.0
qc.config = {
    "type": "bar",
    "data": {
        "labels": ["Yes", "No"],
        "datasets": [{
            "label": "Yes or No",
            "data": [1, 2]
        }]
    }
}
qc_url = (qc.get_url)
```

The site loads as follows:

[image]

I can copy and paste the URL in a browser and it displays as intended. Just trying to figure out how I can have this appear from HTML as an embedded image.

Comment: please share your view, also if it is a non-dynamic url why not just hardcode it?

Comment: Thanks for the note - adding my view code. 

Eventually, I'll add a dropdown menu that will change the output of the image so it will become dynamic beyond just loading the initial URL.

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake on my part. HTML should be:

```
{% block content %}
    <img src= {{ quickchart_url }}>
    <p>{{ quickchart_url }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```